# Dynamic Method Invocation without Reflection

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Does anyone knows how can I invoke method dynamically without reflection?

I`ll try to specify my question below

Suppose we have an interface `IMyInterface` and `MyImplementation` is an implementation of `IMyInterface`. Besides of that I have a generic proxy class `MyProxy<T> where T : IMyInterface`. In this proxy I wanna wrap all calls to all methods that have been defined in `MyImplementation` and in all inheritors of this class. The purpose I wanna achieve is the dynamic method invocation. In case of reflection everything will be transparent, but as I understand it might be quite slow. Does anyone know about solution that could be much faster?

Thanks a lot!

-- update

hmm, looks like my previous descriptions was not good, so I`ll try to describe my question again. With examples :)

So, lets imagine that we have the following code:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
     void Method();
}

public class MyImplementation : IMyInterface
{
     public void Method()
     {
          Console.WriteLine("Yeaah!");
     }
}
```

The important point that I forgot to mention is that we have a class named for example Holder. This class should be used by the following way

```
var holder = // the way of instantiation doesn`t really matters
holder.Register(myImplementationInstance);

var myInterfaceInstance = holder.Resolve<IMyInterface>();
myInterfaceInstance.Method();
```

Holder instance will return some wrapper that will implement `IMyInterface` and will wrap the real instance of myImplementation that has been registered.

As I said above we have a wrapper `MyImplementationWrapper` that implements `IMyInterface` and has the method named Method with the following body

```
public void Method()
{
    _wrappedInstance.Method();
}
```

So, there are two questions
a) How can I automatically create the wrapper for `myImplementationInstance` (I don`t want to know anything about object that will be registred in`Holder`)
b) How can I dynamically invoke the methods of`myImplementationInstance` by its wrapper

Comment: When you say "dynamic," this seems to conflict with the description you've given.  If you have an interface to code against, you can simply forward the calls, which will not use reflections at all.  Can you give a (pseudo) code example?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "wrap all calls to all methods that have been defined in MyImplementation and in all inheritors of this class."? With an example, preferably.

Comment: I`ve described example, so could you check this question again? :)

Comment: you should include the version of the framework, and add more on why you think reflection would be too slow about your needs (it might not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first. Have you made sure that Reflection is not too slow for your needs? Do not go on hearsay - test it yourself.

Edit: To include the use of dynamic

Secondly if you are in the .net 3.5 or .net 4.0 then you can use Iron Python (or in the case of the 4.0 - any DLR language or dynamic) to do the dynamic invocation.

The DLR is a very optimal solution for this kind of thing. In C# you can use the dynamic keyword to access the dlr

Comment: Or if he is using C# 4.0, he can use the `dynamic` keyword, if that is actually what he is trying to do.  Either one is some form of dynamic method invocation using object metadata, or, in a generic sense, reflections.

Comment: +1 for checking if he can just use reflection, I'd bet is a non issue in this case. Agree with Merlyn, I'd use dynamic in 4.0

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. It sounds, though, that what you want is a [decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern), which does not require reflection.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like you're trying to re-implement polymorphism...

```
class MyBaseImplementation
{
    public virtual void MyMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base");
    }
}

class MyDerivedImplementation : MyBaseImplementation
{
    public override void MyMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Derived");
    }
}

static void DoSomething(MyBaseImplementation instance)
{
    instance.MyMethod();
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MyBaseImplementation inst = new MyDerivedImplementation();
    DoSomething(inst);
}
```

This will print "Derived", even though the parameter in the function is of type "MyBaseImplementation"